# How to add a footnote to an equation number?

Tags: equations, footnotes

I would like to add a footnote to an equation number. For example, it should look like:

[image]

(This figure is taken from MS word.)

Does anyone know how to do this in latex? I have tried the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}\refstepcounter{equation}
  a=b \tag*{(\theequation)\protect\footnotemark}
\end{equation}
\footnotetext{A footnote}

Equation \ref{eq1} is a good equation.

\end{document}
```

But each time the equation is referenced, a new superscript will appear like:

[image]

(This is from latex.)

When the equation is referenced, a new superscript shows up. How to avoid it?

Comment: But why do you want to add the foot note to the tag, instead of at the end of the formula?

Comment: If adding a footnote at the end of the formula, it is confusing because the superscript of the footnote is similar to a symbol in the equation.

Comment: In such a case, I would write at the end of the formula  something like `\quad\footnotemark`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution, with the `\newtagform`, `usetagform` commands from `mathtools`. However, you can't use `\eqref` nor `\cref` for equations with footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{fn}{(}{)\footnotemark}

\begin{document}

\usetagform{fn}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
  a=b
\end{equation}
\footnotetext{Some text. }
Equation (\ref{eq1}) is a good equation.
\usetagform{default}
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
  c = d
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]